# google home app recognising the google AIY voice kit as a light

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-aiy

I recently bought and setup the google aiy voice kit, using the google assistant sdk. When I opened up my google home app, I noticed the voice kit being detected as a light, I was wondering if this could be changed so that I can use it a a google home like device (smart speaker).[image: This is what shows up on the google home app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'type' of device is mostly just used for semantic reasons. If I were to say "turn off the *light*", then the Google Assistant would be able to check the lights I may have connected to my account. (The Google Assistant SDK does not support remote execution of commands.)

The *types* of devices that exist are different from the capabilities or *traits* of a device. It does not prevent you from using the AIY kit as a smart speaker, and if you follow guides on [registering a device model](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/register-device) you can change the semantic type.